# Как вывести ровные столбцы в консоли в двухмерном списке python

Tags: python, print

У меня есть двумерный массив

```
[['⏹', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], ['1', '♜', '♞', '♝', '♚', '♛', '♝', '♞', '♜'], ['2', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟'], ['3', ' ', '⏹', ' ', '⏹', ' ', '⏹', ' ', '⏹'], ['4', '⏹', ' ', '⏹', ' ', '⏹', ' ', '⏹', ' '], ['5', ' ', '⏹', ' ', '⏹', ' ', '⏹', ' ', '⏹'], ['6', '⏹', ' ', '⏹', ' ', '⏹', ' ', '⏹', ' '], ['7', '♙', '♙', '♙', '♙', '♙', '♙', '♙', '♙'], ['8', '♖', '♘', '♗', '♔', '♕', '♗', '♘', '♖']]
```

если вывожу вот так:

```
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        print(str(pole[i][j]), end=' ')
    print()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал библиотеку PrettyTable, тоже неровно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы столбцы были ровно друг под другом?

Comment: Шрифт какой стоит?

Comment: где его можно посмотреть?

Comment: Я использую консоль в PyCharm, так как в командной строке символы не отображаются

Comment: Windows Terminal не пробовали?

Comment: Нужен моноширинный шрифт, но будут ли в нём все нужные символы - вопрос

Comment: Перепробовал все monospaced шрифты в PyCharm, отоброжается как на первой картинке, в cmd и powershell символы не отображаются